# $\int_0^1[ \int_0^x$ $ f(x,y)\,dy]dx$ = $\int_0^1[ \int_y^1 f(x,y)\,dx]dy$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be integrable on $[0, 1] × [0, 1]$.

Show that

$\int_0^1[ \int_0^x f(x,y)\,dy]dx =\int_0^1[ \int_y^1$ $ f(x,y)\,dx]dy$

This is my first problem on the double Lebesgue integral so if someone could explain a bit about what's going on that would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think you want ``$dx\,dy$'' as the order of integration on the right-hand side of your equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Big Hint**:

For $x,y \in [0,1]$ you have
$$
1_{[0,x)}(y) = \begin{cases}
1 & 0 \leq y < x \leq 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
1_{(y,1]}(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & 0 \leq y < x \leq 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Hence, for $x,y \in [0,1]$, you find $1_{[0,x)}(y) = 1_{(y,1]}(x)$. Now, notice that
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(x,y) \,dy\,dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 1_{[0,x)}(y)\,f(x,y)\,dy\,dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 1_{(y,1]}(x)\,f(x,y)\,dy\,dx
$$

Use Fubini-Tonelli.

Comment: got it, thanks!